# Application of Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $g(x)=0$ for $x \in [0,1]^c$. Let $\mathcal{A} =\{ \phi_k: x \mapsto g(x-k) | k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a subset of $C([0,1])$. Why does the application of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem fail for $\mathcal{A}$ (w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_{\sup})$?

Comment: I forgot to add that we consider the norm $\| \cdot \|_{sup}$. Then it should be bounded by $\|g\|_{sup}$

Comment: Why do you think it fails? For a given $x\in [0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is only one $\phi_k$ that is not identically zero on $[0,1]$. That is $\phi_0$. So, equicontinuity is true just because $\phi_0=g$ is continuous. Likewise for uniformly bounded. The thesis of the theorem is also true since the sequence is all zero except for $\phi_0$. Now, that is on $[0,1]$. On $\mathbb{R}$, the theorem fails because one is trying to apply it on a non-compact interval.